# How to upgrade a Visual Studio project from within a GitHub action?

Tags: visual-studio, github-actions

A Visual Studio project can be upgraded from the command line using the `devenv.exe` command as follows:

```
  devenv.exe SOLUTION_PATH /Upgrade
```

Where SOLUTION_PATH is a path to a Visual Studio solution (or project) file.

What is the most direct way to perform this step as part of a GitHub action?

**What I Have Tried**

So far I have failed to find a way to get `devenv.exe` into the path of the GitHub Action. There does not appear to be a prebuilt action step for this (`setup-msbuild` step does not make `devenv` available). Even hardcoding a path such as

```
 MSDEVENV_PATH: ${{'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.com'}}

... then later ...

run: ${{env.MSDEVENV_PATH}} ${{env.SOLUTION_FILE_PATH}} /Upgrade
```

fails because the path contains spaces, and I can find no way to add quotation marks.

I am aware of [a way to find devenv using powershell and extra downloadable packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42713238/reliable-way-to-find-the-location-devenv-exe-of-visual-studio-2017) however this will require writing a PowerShell script, and presumably signing it, and I have no idea whether this will even work in a GitHub Action. Perhaps there is a much simpler approach, hence my question: what is the most *direct* way to upgrade a solution?

Comment: What does this `Upgrade` actually do?

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej It upgrades the project file version from .vcproj to .vcxproj: https://learn.microsoft.com/lb-lu/visualstudio/ide/reference/upgrade-devenv-exe?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 2):

You need a Windows-based runner. `vswhere` is the tool to get path to various components of the Visual Studio installation and its folder is in the path ([source](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/346)).

```
run: |
  $devenv = & vswhere.exe '-property' productPath
  Start-Process -FilePath $devenv -ArgumentList '${{env.SOLUTION_FILE_PATH}} /Upgrade' -Wait
```

Comment: Does this solution actually work for you? For me I think the step exits before the asynchronous devenv process has finished updating the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @riQQ's partial answer I currently have the following, which waits for the output to be done using both a pipe to `Out-Null` suggested in [this answer](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48896010/occasionally-occurring-msbuild-error-msb3428/48918105#48918105) and also waits for the generated files to appear. Note that I am using a path to the *project* not to the *solution*. (I could not get solution upgrading to work correctly, although I never worked out why.)

```
run: |
    $devenv = & vswhere.exe '-property' productPath
    Write-Output "$devenv"
    & $devenv "${{env.VCPROJ_FILE_PATH}}" /Upgrade /NoSplash | Out-Null
    Write-Output "devenv launched"
    while (!(Test-Path "${{env.VCXPROJ_FILE_PATH}}")) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 10 }
    Write-Output "vcxproj found"
    while (!(Test-Path "${{env.VCXPROJ_FILTERS_FILE_PATH}}")) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 10 }
    Write-Output "vcxproj.filters found"
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    Write-Output "done."
```

For some reason this step is taking over 5 minutes to complete when run as part of a GitHub Action. It takes only a few seconds on my local machine. Because of the nasty file polling I don't consider this an ideal solution, but I am posting it here for reference.

Comment: The slow `devenv.exe` may be due to this GitHub actions issue: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/128